# querying a table with timestamptz using milliseconds and +-<hours> for timezone

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.4 for my project.

I have a table with a `mytime` column of type `timestamptz`.

I was wondering if there is a way to query the table with milliseconds for epoch time and instead of specifying a timezone i can specify the hours difference.

for example.. Israel time is +2 and current epoch time is 1563447152, so is there a way to ask for row with older mytime value then 1563447152 with a timezone of +2 ?

I know that I can do:

```
timezone('Israel',to_timestamp(1563447152))
```

but is there another function to give it +2 instead of Israel?

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once you obfuscate your timestamp (TZ)  information by converting it to a plain number, this will get hard. Why don't you simply use `mytime + interval '2 hour'` and use the resulting `timestamptz`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - that's actually an awesome idea! so first I need to get the time in UTC timezone or something right ?

Comment: No, if that is a `timestamptz` you don't need to do anything

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - ok thanks i'll check it out and post my findings :)